# Angular2 Material Table Error

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an Angular Material Table using Angular2.

My data is retrieved correctly, and as far as I can tell my table looks OK. I am delaying the initialisation of the table until the data is retrieved to ensure that is not the issue. However, I come across the issue:

`Cannot read property 'diff' of undefined`

My HTML is as follows:

```
`<div *ngIf="repacksReturned">
     <md-table #table [dataSource]="openRepacks">
         <ng-container cdkColumnDef="ID">
             <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
             <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.ID}}</md-cell>
         </ng-container>

         <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
         <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
     </md-table>
</div>`
```

My type script is as follows:

```
export class JobComponent implements OnInit {
    openRepacks = new Array<RepackRequest>();
    repacksReturned = false;
    displayedColumns: ['ID'];

    constructor(private repackService: RepackService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getOpenRepacks();
    }

    getOpenRepacks(): void {
        this.repackService.GetOpenRepacks()
                  .subscribe((data: RepackRequest[]) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.openRepacks = data;
                    this.repacksReturned = true;
                  });
    }
}
```

I have had a look around and cant find anything that has resolved this.

Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**

Stacktrace from console

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'diff' of undefined
at CdkRowDef.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk/table.es5.js.BaseRowDef.getColumnsDiff (table.es5.js:53)
at table.es5.js:533
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at QueryList.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.QueryList.forEach (core.es5.js:5534)
at MdTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk/table.es5.js.CdkTable._renderUpdatedColumns (table.es5.js:532)
at MdTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk/table.es5.js.CdkTable.ngAfterContentChecked (table.es5.js:493)
at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11199)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11177)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11161)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12266)
```

Comment: What version of Angular and Material are you using?

Comment: i don't see in your code where you are trying to use property 'diff '

Comment: im not thats the thing. i assume it is built in to the md-table component?

Comment: I am using angular material from here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples and angular 4. unsure as to how to find an exact version number

Comment: Go to `node_modules/@angular/material/package.json` and check the version there. Yes diff is used in the md-table to monitor data changes

Comment: _id is @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.10 and nodeVersion is "6.10.3" not sure which is the correct value

Comment: and angular core looks like version 4.4.3

Comment: try this. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6831

Comment: But the columns are not null or undefined. i set the columns before doing anything